# PHP - How to compare file modification date with current date

Tags: php

I want to compare the file modification date with the current date.

I tried the following (which is working for the current Time):

```
$currentDay = date("d");
$currentMonth = date("m");
$currentYear = date("y");
$currentHour = date("h");
$currentMinute = date("i");
```

Now i tried to get the file modification year from my file:

```
$subst1 = file("f1/subst_001.htm");
$mod_date=date("y", filemtime($subst1));
echo $mod_date;
```

But it's giving me for year "70", which is coming from the Year 1970, what did i do wrong?

And no, i already checked if the file says this creation year...

Comment: you could just simply compare them by unix timestamps, using both `time()` and `filemtime('path/to/file')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [filetime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) function expects `string` as file path. Here you are trying to pass an `array` that is returned from [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Try like this way,

```
$filename= "f1/subst_001.htm";
if (file_exists($filename)) {
   $mod_date = date("y", filemtime($filename));
   echo $mod_date;
}
```

> January 1, 1970 is the so called Unix epoch. It's the date where they
>   started counting the Unix time. If you get this date as a return
>   value, it usually means that the conversion of your date to the Unix
>   timestamp returned a (near-) zero result. So the date conversion
>   doesn't succeed. Most likely because it receives a wrong input.

**Courtesy** : Oldskool

Comment: Thank you! It works now, there were so many posts about reading current time but nearly no post that said how you could read the modification time from a file in php, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Use the correct date format parameter.

'y' returns a two digit representation of the year:

```
date ("y", filemtime($filename)) // 18
```

'Y' returns the four digit representation of the year:

```
date ("Y", filemtime($filename)) // 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mod_date=date("y", filemtime("f1/subst_001.htm"));
echo $mod_date;
```

`filemtime()` takes `string:pathname` as its parameter but `file()` function reads a file into an array. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using var_dump on the filemtime result - it is probably false (or something which converts to int 0).  Since time 0 is January 1, 1970, that would explain why the year is '70'.

If that's the case, it's not finding your file.